# $addToSet Based on Object key exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have array `'pets': [{'fido': ['abc']}` that is a embeded document. When I add a pet to the array, how can I check to see if that pet already exists? For instance, if I added fido again... how can I check if only `fido` exists and not add it? I was hoping I could use `$addToSet` but I only want to check part of the set(the pets name).

```
User.prototype.updatePetArray = function(userId, petName) {
  userId = { _id: ObjectId(userId) };
  return this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(userId,
    { $addToSet: { pets: { [petName]: [] } } },
    { returnOriginal: false,
      maxTimeMS: QUERY_TIME });
```

Result of adding `fido` twice:

```
{u'lastErrorObject': {u'updatedExisting': True, u'n': 1}, u'ok': 1, u'value': {u'username': u'bob123', u'_id': u'56d5fc8381c9c28b3056f794', u'location': u'AT', u'pets': [{u'fido': []}]}}

{u'lastErrorObject': {u'updatedExisting': True, u'n': 1}, u'ok': 1, u'value': {u'username': u'bob123', u'_id': u'56d5fc8381c9c28b3056f794', u'location': u'AT', u'pets': [{u'fido': [u'abc']}, {u'fido': []}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always going to be "variable" content within each member of the `"pets"` array ( i.e petName as the key ) then [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is not for you. At least not not at the array level where you are looking to apply it.

Instead you basically need an [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) test on the "key" of the document being contained in the array, then either `$addToSet` to the "contained" array of that matched key with the [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator, **or** where the "key" was not matched then [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) directly to the "pets" array, with the new inner `content` directly as the sole array member.

So if you can live with not returning the modified document, then "Bulk" operations are for you. In modern drivers with [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite):

```
User.prototype.updatePetArray = function(userId, petName, content) {
    var filter1 = { "_id": ObjectId(userId) },
        filter2 = { "_id": ObjectId(userId) },
        update1 = { "$addToSet": {} },
        update2 = { "$push": { "pets": {} } };

    filter1["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": true };
    filter2["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": false };

    var setter1 = {};
    setter1["pets.$." + petName] = content;
    update1["$addToSet"] = setter1;

    var setter2 = {};
    setter2[petName] = [content];
    update2["$push"]["pets"] = setter2;

    // Return the promise that yields the BulkWriteResult of both calls
    return this.collection.bulkWrite([
        { "updateOne": {
            "filter": filter1,
            "update": update1
        }},
        { "updateOne": {
            "filter": filter2,
            "update": update2
        }}
    ]);
};
```

If you must return the modified document, then you are going to need to resolve each call and return the one that actually matched something:

```
User.prototype.updatePetArray = function(userId, petName, content) {
    var filter1 = { "_id": ObjectId(userId) },
        filter2 = { "_id": ObjectId(userId) },
        update1 = { "$addToSet": {} },
        update2 = { "$push": { "pets": {} } };

    filter1["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": true };
    filter2["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": false };

    var setter1 = {};
    setter1["pets.$." + petName] = content;
    update1["$addToSet"] = setter1;

    var setter2 = {};
    setter2[petName] = [content];
    update2["$push"]["pets"] = setter2;

    // Return the promise that returns the result that matched and modified
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var operations = [
            this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter1,update1,{ "returnOriginal": false}),
            this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter2,update2,{ "returnOriginal": false})
        ];

        // Promise.all runs both, and discard the null document
        Promise.all(operations).then(function(result) {
            resolve(result.filter(function(el) { return el.value != null } )[0].value);
        },reject);

    });
};
```

In either case this requires "two" update attempts where only "one" will actually succeed and modify the document, since only one of the `$exists` tests is going to be true.

So as an example of that first case, the "query" and "update" are resolving after interpolation as:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("56d7b759e955e2812c6c8c1b"),
    "pets.fido": { "$exists": true } 
},
{ "$addToSet": { "pets.$.fido": "ccc" } }
```

And the second update as:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("56d7b759e955e2812c6c8c1b"),
    "pets.fido": { "$exists": false } 
},
{ "$push": { "pets": { "fido": ["ccc"]  } } }
```

Given varibles of:

```
userId = "56d7b759e955e2812c6c8c1b",
petName = "fido",
content = "ccc";
```

Personally I would not be naming keys like this, but rather change the structure to:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56d7b759e955e2812c6c8c1b"),
    "pets": [{ "name": "fido", "data": ["abc"] }]
}
```

That makes the update statements easier, and without the need for variable interpolation into the key names. For example:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(userId),
    "pets.name": petName
},
{ "$addToSet": { "pets.$.data": content } }
```

and:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(userId),
    "pets.name": { "$ne": petName }
},
{ "$push": { "pets": { "name": petName, "data": [content] } } }
```

Which feels a whole lot cleaner and can actually use an "index" for matching, which of course `$exists` simply cannot.

There is of course more overhead if using [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate), since this is afterall "two" actual calls to the server for which you need to await a response as opposed to the Bulk method which is just "one".

But if you need the returned document ( option is the default in the driver anyway ) then either do that or similarly await the Promise resolve from the `.bulkWrite()` and then fetch the document via `.findOne()` after completion. Albeit that doing it via `.findOne()` after the modification would not truly be "atomic" and could possibly return the document "after" another similar modification was made, and not only in the state of that particular change.

---

N.B Also assuming that apart from the keys of the subdocuments in `"pets"` as a "set" that your other intention for the array contained was adding to that "set" as well via the additional `content` supplied to the function. If you just wanted to overwrite a value, then just apply `$set` instead of `$addToSet` and similarly wrap as an array.

But it sounds reasonable that the former was what you were asking.

BTW. Please clean up by horrible setup code in this example for the query and update objects in your actual code :)

---

As a self contained listing to demonstrate:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  var coll = db.collection('pettest');

  var petName = "fido",
      content = "bbb";

  var filter1 = { "_id": 1 },
      filter2 = { "_id": 1 },
      update1 = { "$addToSet": {} },
      update2 = { "$push": { "pets": {} } };

  filter1["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": true };
  filter2["pets." + petName] = { "$exists": false };

  var setter1 = {};
  setter1["pets.$." + petName] = content;
  update1["$addToSet"] = setter1;

  var setter2 = {};
  setter2[petName] = [content];
  update2["$push"]["pets"] = setter2;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(update1,undefined,2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(update2,undefined,2));

  function CleanInsert(callback) {
    async.series(
      [
        // Clean data
        function(callback) {
          coll.deleteMany({},callback);
        },
        // Insert sample
        function(callback) {
          coll.insert({ "_id": 1, "pets": [{ "fido": ["abc"] }] },callback);
        }
      ],
      callback
    );
  }

  async.series(
    [
      CleanInsert,
      // Modify Bulk
      function(callback) {

        coll.bulkWrite([
          { "updateOne": {
            "filter": filter1,
            "update": update1
          }},
          { "updateOne": {
            "filter": filter2,
            "update": update2
          }}
        ]).then(function(res) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2));
          coll.findOne({ "_id": 1 }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2));
            callback();
          });
        },callback);
      },
      CleanInsert,
      // Modify Promise all
      function(callback) {
        var operations = [
          coll.findOneAndUpdate(filter1,update1,{ "returnOriginal": false }),
          coll.findOneAndUpdate(filter2,update2,{ "returnOriginal": false })
        ];

        Promise.all(operations).then(function(res) {

          //console.log(JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2));

          console.log(
            JSON.stringify(
              res.filter(function(el) { return el.value != null })[0].value
            )
          );
          callback();
        },callback);
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    }

  );

});
```

And the output:

```
{
  "$addToSet": {
    "pets.$.fido": "bbb"
  }
}
{
  "$push": {
    "pets": {
      "fido": [
        "bbb"
      ]
    }
  }
}
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "insertedIds": [],
  "nInserted": 0,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nMatched": 1,
  "nModified": 1,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": []
}
{
  "_id": 1,
  "pets": [
    {
      "fido": [
        "abc",
        "bbb"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{"_id":1,"pets":[{"fido":["abc","bbb"]}]}
```

Feel free to change to different values to see how different "sets" are applied.

Comment: Thanks! I originally had ` "pets": [{ "name": "fido", "data": ["abc"] }]` and thought it was not as good. I will change that back...thanks for confirming this also.

Comment: I would like to avoid the extra index on `pets` array if possible, to save on memory. Since `pets` array is a embedded document of User doc, wouldn't searching indexed `_id: ObjectId()` be enough? Would I still be able to use `"pets.fido": { "$exists": false } ` and `"pets.name": { "$ne": petName }` without the extra index and the same performance?

Comment: @dman As long as you are including the `_id` in the query it would be a non-issue since the document would already be selected by that value. Where it would structurally make a difference and where index benefits come in is when you want to do any sort of analysis across documents on this source. Named keys really don't work well on analysis, which is a strong reason to avoid them. As for your memory concerns, this get's brought up over and over again, but the real difference is negligible, and even more so under wired tiger ( which internally hashes keys ).

Comment: @dman So the main advice here is don't overoptimize out the programming convienice and readability, along with future analysis options just for the sake of what you "think" is going to save you a few bytes. The real case is that it truly won't save much or anything at all. At any rate, Equality match outer array to modify, and in-equality match to add gives you a "true" equivanet operation to controlling "sets". But you do need two statements to control both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one with [string template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), here is one example running under mongo shell

```
> var name = 'fido';
> var t = `pets.${name}`; \\ string temple, could parse name variable
> db.pets.find()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56d7b5019ed174b9eae2b9c5"), "pets" : [ { "fido" : [ "abc" ]} ] }
```

With the following `update` command, it will not update it if the same pet name exists.

```
> db.pets.update({[t]: {$exists: false}}, {$addToSet: {pets: {[name]: []}}})
   WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

---

If the `pets` document is

```
> db.pets.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d7b7149ed174b9eae2b9c6"), "pets" : [ { "fi" : [ "abc" ] } ] }
```

After update with

```
> db.pets.update({[t]: {$exists: false}}, {$addToSet: {pets: {[name]: []}}})
  WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

The result shows add the pet name if it does Not exist.

```
> db.pets.find()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56d7b7149ed174b9eae2b9c6"), "pets" : [ { "fi" : [ "abc" ] }, { "fido" : [ ] } ] }
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Keys "stringify" so it's looking for both `t` and trying to add `[name]` as the keys and not the variable interpolations. Also nowhere near that simple

Comment: @BlakesSeven, my bad, I make mistake for previous answer. I have updated my answer with some test codes. It seems well now?

Comment: I have not tried this yet...as I might change the array structure. But this is an excellent idea! I like how clean it is also.