# Set field if doesn't exist, push to array, then return document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was hoping to do this in one operation, with just hitting the database once... but I don't know if it's possible with the api's.....

what I want is to:

1. find the document by id(which always will exist)
2. add object if it doesn't already exist `{ dayOfYear: 3, dataStuff: [{time:
   Date(arg), data: 123] }`
3. push `{time: Date(arg), data: 123] }` to `dataStuff` array
4. return modified document

I cooked up something along the lines of

```
  return this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(dataDoc,
    { $set: { dayOfYear: reqBody.dayOfYear ,
      $addToSet: { dataStuff: { time: Date(reqBody.date), data: reqBody.data } 
    }
```

but no success

Comment: This is more than a little unclear what you are asking. There are syntactical errors in the statement and also lessons you should already have learned from previous questions. I don't know if you are asking for a different approach to your previous question response [$addToSet Based on Object key exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35762783/5031275) or not. If that is what you are asking again, then there are reasons why that is not a single update, and those reasons should all be well explained.

Comment: Could you give some feedback? You clearly have visited the site since posting and it can only help you to make it clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: With the MongoDb apis given, I am not going to be able to go forward with my design properly as there would be recursion in embedded documents. I will have to break it up into multi documents and use normalization. Because of the normalization, I am going to look at PostgreSQL since it's dedicated relational database. MongoDb was my choice for denormalization, but not for normalization.

Comment: That doesn't really make your question clearer ( which was the sole point of the commentary ) and neither does the general silence. What I was after was a clear problem statement. 1. Source data to modify, 2. Actual modification statement and expected match 3. Expected result. We can let the answers stand, but the reason I was asking was that it's unclear if either response is appropriate to what you intend to ask. So it's "for your benefit" ultimately to be as clear as possible. Right now your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The update object needs "seperate" top level keys for each atomic operation:

```js
return this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  dataDoc,
  {
      "$set": { dayOfYear: reqBody.dayOfYear },
      "$addToSet": { 
          "dataStuff": { "time": Date(reqBody.date), "data": reqBody.data  } 
      }
  },
  { "returnOriginal": false }
)
```

With [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) from the core API you also need to set the `"returnOrginal"` option to `false` in order to return the modified document. With the [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) API, it is `{ "new": true }` instead.

In this syntax, both calls are returning a "Promise" to be resolved, and not just a direct response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the whole object exists, you'll have to compare all the properties, like

```
this.collections.update({
  _id: dataDoc,
  dayOfYear: {
    $ne: reqBody.dayOfYear
  },
  dataStuff: {
    $elemMatch: {
      time: {
        $ne: Date(arg)
      },
      data: {
        $ne: reqBody.data
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    dayOfYear: reqBody.dayOfYear,
  },
  $addToSet: {
    dataStuff: {
      time: Date(arg),
      data: reqBody.data
    }
  }
});
```

This way, you ensure that you always update *one or zero* collection items. The first argument is the query that either returns no elements or a single element (because `_id` is there), and if it returns one element, it gets updated. Which is, I believe, exactly what you need.